# setting java classpath for Libre Office Base in Fedora 16

Tags: java, mysql, fedora16, libreoffice-base

using Fedora 16 OS.  i want to use Libre Office Base to connect to MySQL.  when i set up the JDBC connection, it asks me for the driver, however, it cannot be loaded (because it doesn't see it in the classpath).

does anybody know how to set the classpath for Libre Office?  is there like a config util tool for that?

e.g. my driver is [B]com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [/B]situated in[B] /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar[/B].  it works fine when i connect from other JDBC clients, like straight Java or Eclipse Quantum plugin.  the problem is that Libre Office does not ask me for the (class)path of where it can find the driver and i do not know where and how to set it so that it becomes visible.

thanks

Comment: Is the CLASSPATH environment variable set in your .profile or .bash_profile script?

Comment: it is but it doesn't pick it up.  i think there may be a place to set the classpath for just the Libre Office apps so they can see it but i just don't know where it is.  thanks anyway

Comment: Almost no application uses the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

This is old but Libre Office does not honor CLASSPATH. You have to close Base, **open writer** and add the /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar jar file on menu:

Tools > Options > Java, hit the "Class Path" button and add the jar in the dialog that pops up.

Close writer, open Base and your driver have to be recognized.